# MVC razor, how to make input for DateTime picker with Timestamp?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

for a school project i'm assigned to make a reservation service where the admin can choose a date and a time of an event.

so far i've managed to get following razor code working. The first line gives me a datepicker, wich is very handy. and the second one gives me a time picker.

```
@html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StartTime,"{0:yyyy-MM-dd}" htmlAttributes: new { @class="form-control" , @type = "date"})

@html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StartTime, htmlAttributes: new {@class="form-control", @type = "time"})
```

The problem is that i have 2 different inputs and none of them gives a DateTime that would be assigned correctly (read: correct value) to my model when i submit this page.

Any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: You need to different `DateTime` properties (one should be `DateTime` for the date component and the other `TimeSpan` for the time component) which you can combine into one `DateTime`. but why not just use a jquery datetimepicker? (you do realize that the HTML5 controls for `type="date"` and `type="time"` are only supported in Chrome and Edge?)

Comment: Or you can use `<input type="datetime-local">`, I don't know how much it's supported among browsers though.

Comment: No i didn't know that, thanks Stephen. 
And i've already tried the DateTime as type but that just gives an empty textbox where the user needs to manually type the date like this: 2016/5/3 11:23:23 
The jquery i found so far only provided a date, without time. 
I'll try to make 2 inputs and combine them, like you say.

Comment: @ArnoDh, There a plenty of jquery datetimepickers, including [this one](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

Comment: @StephenMuecke ok, i'm gonna try one of those. Looks promising. Thanks for your replies!